# Can I use 'shield off'

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

Can I use 'shield off'? Here is an example:

> The volunteers encourage the visitors to speak with John, rather than shielding him off.

Comment: Thank you, k1eran.  I take your edit for a 'yes'. BTW, cool Irish name! Cheers

Comment: There are an estimated 136 hits in Google Books for [(something) **is shielded off** from (whatever is being prevented from reaching it)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+shielded+off+from%22) Plus [another 286](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+shielded+off%22+-%22is+shielded+off+from%22) without that (optional) ***from-*** clause. Also note that ***away*** is usually an acceptable alternative to ***off*** in this construction.

Comment: Thank you, FumbleFingers - but here are a few things to considerate: (1) How many of these 136 books are from native speakers, 136 books is not much when taking into account the sheer amount of texts that Google has indexed. (2) 'shield off from' is clearly the same meaning but 'from' is not used in my questions. (3) 3.600 results for all Google web searchers are not a strong indicator for the correctness of this phrase. No one hereon has asked this question ever before. At the end of the day this forum's purpose is to ask a question when in doubt and reliable references are scarce.

Comment: *consider, not 'considerate' ...apologies for any typos/misspellings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence

> The volunteers encourage the visitors to speak with John, rather than
>   shielding him off.

could (romanticly) mean that the visitors might be using war shields to knock John to the floor, because it won't be the volunteers. In other words it may be the visitors who refuse to talk to John. However

> The volunteers encourage the visitors to speak with John, rather than
>   shielding him.

means that the volunteers do not protect John from visitors who want to talk to him.